# Retain the change detection in ag grid react typescript

Tags: reactjs, grid, ag

In AG Grid, when I try the change detection feature in AG grid. It is working fine. However I want to know, Is there any way to retain the changes. The numbers or changes are showing for 5 seconds and later vanishes. I tried to increase the celldelay property and It is vanishing after sometime. Can you help me to retain the changes   and only when I refresh the changes should go off. Please help me.

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/change-detection/

Answer (score 0):

Change Detection is a mechanism of detecting changes in the data you are feeding into the grid. if you want to retain previous changes (I'm assuming you mean retaining old data, if not please clarify what you are asking) then you need to keep a copy of your data and update the grid based on external 'React' states/components instead of directly hooking the data stream (which I'm assuming is getting updated automatically in your case) into the grid.